# Uninstall and/or repair Silverlight installation

Tags: windows-7, silverlight

I have a problem with Silverlight. I keep getting a Silverlight update (KB2512827) via Windows Update, although I already installed it a hundred times by now. I install it, the installation is successful, and when I search for new Windows updates, it just appears again.

So apparently my Silverlight installation is broken. What I wanted to try is that I simply uninstall Silverlight, and then install it again from scratch, so that hopefully the update will become redundant. However, there is no Silverlight entry in my installed program list, and as such, there is no way to uninstall it.

I have tried [different](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308173441/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rpomeroy/archive/2008/06/10/how-to-manually-clean-up-a-bad-silverlight-installation.aspx) [approaches](https://web.archive.org/web/20121106020450/http://darkblak.juansolutions.net:80/manually-remove-uninstall-silverlight/), but in all cases I was even missing the registry entries (and removing the program files folder didn’t do anything either – don’t worry, I just renamed it, so I still have it).

My Silverlight installation actually works. If I visit Silverlight applications, they run perfectly fine, and I can also access the Silverlight preferences either via right-click, or by opening the program myself in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\`.

I also tried simply reinstalling, but instead of actually just reinstalling the software, the installer just tells me that the version I want to install is already installed.

As such it seems that I can’t do anything to remove or reinstall Silverlight. So is there any way to fix this? Btw. simply hiding the entry in Windows update is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure when or why it happened, but the problem fixed itself after ignoring the update long enough.